# Bluebird promise is not calling .then intermittently

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am learning bluebird and implementing in my code as below:

```
var getPromiseA = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 executeCommand('command A')
     .then(function (result) {
         var temp = JSON.parse(result);
         for (var i in temp) {
             if (temp[i].abc === 'ABC') {
                 resolve(temp[i]);
             }
         }
     }).catch(function (err) {
         console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseA :::');
         reject(err);
     });
  });

 var getPromiseB = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     executeCommand('command B')
         .then(function (result) {
             resolve(JSON.parse(result));
         })
         .catch(function (err) {
             console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseB :::');
             reject(err);
         });
 });

 var getPromiseC = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     executeCommand('command C')
         .then(function (result) {
             var temp = JSON.parse(result);
             for (var i in temp) {
                 console.log('in command C::::');
                 if (temp[i].abc != null) {
                     resolve(temp[i]);
                 }
             }
         })
         .catch(function (err) {
             console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseC :::');
             reject(err);
         });
 });

 function executeCommand(inputCmd) {
     var commandPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         var response = {}, err = {};
         var command = exec(inputCmd);
         command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
             response = data;
         });
         command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
             err = data;
         });
         command.on('close', function (code) {
             console.log('coming in close' + code);
             if (code === 0) {
                 console.log('before resolving in executeCommand');
                 resolve(response);
                 console.log('after resolving in executeCommand' + JSON.stringify(response));

             }
             else {
                 reject(code);
             }
         });
     });
     return commandPromise;
 }
```

After this I am using Promise.all function to resolve all promises.
I am facing the issue while resolving getPromiseC. PromiseC is not going into .then.
I am not able to figure out what is the reason.

Output looks like below:
   For getPromiseA -
    1.before resolving in executeCommand
    2.after resolving in executeCommand - {data}
    3.getPromiseA .then

For getPromiseB -
   1.before resolving in executeCommand
   2.after resolving in executeCommand - {data}
   3.getPromiseB .then

For getPromiseC -
   1.before resolving in executeCommand
   2.after resolving in executeCommand - {data}

NOT printing 'getPromiseC .then'
Control stucks here.But when try executing the function again,it resolves all the promises,i.e, I could see getPromiseC .then is printing in my console.

I am stuck since this issue happens intermittently.And the reload resolves the issue.
When I call the function multiple times i see this resolving issue happens randomly.

Can someone help me to learn what is wrong this code?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! (In `getPromiseA`, `getPromiseB` and `getPromiseC`). That will also take care of the case that you're never calling `resolve` (when `temp` is empty).

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks.To remove antipattern,var getPromiseA =
         Promise.resolve(executeCommand('command A').then(function (result) {var temp = JSON.parse(result);for (var i in temp) {if (temp[i].abc === 'ABC') {Promise.resolve(temp[i]);}}}).catch(function (err) {console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseA :::');Promise.reject(err);
})); Here I am using Promise.reject to reject the error.is this the right way to do?

Comment: No, you need to `return` or `throw` something from the `then` callback. Just creating a promise but doing nothing with it will get it ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572):

```
var promiseA = executeCommand('command A').then(function (result) {
    var temp = JSON.parse(result);
    for (var i in temp) {
        if (temp[i].abc === 'ABC') {
            return temp[i];
//          ^^^^^^
        }
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseA :::');
    throw err;
});

var promiseB = executeCommand('command B').then(JSON.parse).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseB :::');
    throw err;
});

var promiseC = executeCommand('command C').then(function (result) {
    var temp = JSON.parse(result);
    for (var i in temp) {
        console.log('in command C::::');
        if (temp[i].abc != null) {
            return temp[i];
//          ^^^^^^
        }
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error occurred while executing getPromiseC :::');
    throw err;
});
```

By that, you will also have eliminated the source of your error: that the promises were never resolved when no appropriate value was found in `temp`. Your promises now will just resolve with the `undefined` value that is implicitly returned by the callback functions.

Comment: Thanks.I am doing exactly what you suggested.I am still facing an intermittent issue here- console goes into then method of promiseB,after that promiseA or promiseC whichever resolves first.But sometimes output is:printing promiseB .then,printing PromiseA .then and PromiseC .then NEVER called.Also another output is printing promiseB .then,printing PromiseC .then and PromiseA .then NEVER called.Note: I am using promise.all after promiseC like this -  Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC].map(function (promise) { console.log('Resolving allpromises::::');return promise.reflect();}))

Comment: If you just don't get the `console.log('in command C::::');` output, that means your loop is not entered (because `temp` has no properties). If the promise never resolves (and also never rejects, as you use `reflect`), this means that `command` never fires a `close` event. Either fix your command, or use `.timeout()`.

Comment: My Bad while posting the comment.I moved console.log('in command C::::'); outside for loop and close event returns data and temp has properties too.like this - var promiseC = executeCommand('command C').then(function (result) {  console.log('in command C::::');   var temp = JSON.parse(result);for (var i in temp) {...

Comment: Also i see that the command fires the close event and give the data.

Comment: No,not working yet.You are right about close event not getting called.When I say my output is stuck(not printing what i expected),this is what happens-It resolves any 2 promises(say A,B) then promise C never get called.Or if B,C resolves ,A is not getting resolved.This happens intermittently as well.When I reload it works as expected.Please refer executeCommand(inputCommand) in my initial post,Should I need to change the anti pattern there as well?Or is it some race condition occurs?I am confused.

Comment: The use of the `Promise` constructor in `executeCommand` is *not* an antipattern, it's genuinely used to promisify a callback API in there. If `close` is never fired, this is probably `exec`'s fault (or your actual command really is a program that doesn't finish). You might want to ask a new question about what the causes for that might be.

Comment: Thanks Bergi.Appreciate the help.As you suggested finally figured out the issue is due to exec's fault.If I issue multiple exec commands,one process is getting stuck during multiple hits.Hence decided to go for synchronous approach to execute each exec one after another.